# std::conditional vs std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a hashing function that can take any object type and hash it, it uses `std::hash` internally. Because `std::hash` does not support enum types I've created overloads of the function, 1 for enumerations using `std::underlying_type` and 1 for other types:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
static std::size_t Hash(T const & t)
{
    return std::hash<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>()(t);
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
static std::size_t Hash(T const & t)
{
    return std::hash<T>()(t);
}
```

This is working fine.
I then tried to put it all into a single function with `std::conditional`:

```
template <typename T>
static std::size_t Hash(T const & t)
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::hash<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>, std::hash<T>>::type Hasher;
    return Hasher()(t);
}
```

Main:

```
enum test
{
    TEST = 2
};

int main() {
    Hash<test>(TEST);
    Hash<int>(5);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This however, gave me an [error](http://ideone.com/CKckZD) :

> /usr/include/c++/5/type_traits:2190:38: error: 'int' is not an enumeration type
>          typedef __underlying_type(_Tp) type;

I do understand the error but I don't understand why, I thought `std::conditional` would prevent these compile-time errors because `<int>` uses `std::hash<T>` instead of  `std::hash<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>` at compile-time.

What am I doing wrong here, is there a way I can merge the 2 functions?

Comment: In short, `conditional` requires both 'branches' to be well-formed. Merging both branches can be done with a traits struct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `std::underlying_type` is not well-formed if the template argument is not an enum, and both branches of `std::conditional` need to be valid.

One possibility would be to make a `safe_underlying_type` trait which just returns `void` if `T` is not an enum:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::is_enum<T>::type>
struct safe_underlying_type {
    using type = void;
};

template <typename T>
struct safe_underlying_type<T, std::true_type> {
    using type = std::underlying_type_t<T>; 
};
```

Or you could just write a trait to get the hash type you want:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::is_enum<T>::type>
struct hash_type {
    using type = std::hash<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct hash_type<T, std::true_type> {
    using type = std::hash<std::underlying_type_t<T>>;  
};
```

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to use `conditional`, you'll need to defer evaluation:

```
template<class T> struct identity { using type = T; };

using Hasher = std::hash<typename std::conditional<std::is_enum<T>::value,
                                                   std::underlying_type<T>,
                                                   identity<T>>::type::type>;
```

Also, `std::hash` should natively support enums since [LWG 2148](http://wg21.link/lwg2148).

Answer (score 2):

Both types (branches) used in the `conditional` need to be well formed when they are evaluated at compile time.

The issue is that when the compiler parses the `std::conditional` itself, the statement `typename std::underlying_type<T>::type` needs to be well formed (and it is not for the `int`). It doesn't really matter what the result is yet, it hasn't got that far.

Answer (score 2):

`typename std::underlying_type<T>::type`

This is not well-formed for an `int`, but it is still evaluated at compile time. That's why you're getting this error. You already gave a solution using `std::enable_if`, so I'm not go into details there. I think it is fine and using `std::conditional` would just make it harder to read anyway.